# Rspec with Rails - url_helpers outside before/it blocks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In my app, I have an identical form on two separate pages. I've written a series of tests for the one page, and would like to simply loop over the test suite for my second page, passing in the page for which the test suite should run against. The problem is, I can't seem to access the `url_helpers` in a clean way.

This is what I have so far that works:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe "my tests" do
  subject { page }

  paths = ["/signin", "/signup"]
  paths.each do |path|
    describe "user signs in via #{path}" do
      before { visit path }

      describe "user enters invalid information" do
        before do
          fill_in "Email", with: user.email, match: :first
          fill_in "Password", with: user.password.reverse, match: :first
          click_button "Sign in"
        end

        it { should have_title("Sign in") }
        it { should have_content "Invalid email/password combination!" }
        its(:current_path) { should eq "/signin" }
      end
  end
end
```

If I replace `"/signin"` with `signin_path`, I get

```
undefined local variable or method `signin_path' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::Authentication:Class (NameError)
```

But I'm using url_helpers successfully throughout the rest of my test script, albeit inside before and it blocks. If I fully qualify the url_helper with `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.signin_path` it works, but I'd rather have this work automatically. If I do an include at the top of the script, I get

```
ActionView::Template::Error:
   arguments passed to url_for can't be handled. Please require routes or provide your own implementation
```

Again, not ideal. I'd rather have this just work. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are there no errors if you just did one path? If so, then why not use a [RSpec shared_example](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core#shared-examples-and-contexts)

```
require 'rails_helper'

shared_examples 'get_user_in' do |path|
    describe "user signs in via #{path}" do
      before { visit path }

      describe "user enters invalid information" do
        before do
          fill_in "Email", with: user.email, match: :first
          fill_in "Password", with: user.password.reverse, match: :first
          click_button "Sign in"
        end

        it { should have_title("Sign in") }
        it { should have_content "Invalid email/password combination!" }
        its(:current_path) { should eq "/signin" }
      end
  end
end

describe "/signin" do
  subject { page }
  include_examples "get_user_in", 'signin'
end

describe "/signup" do
  subject { page }
  include_examples "get_user_in", 'signup'
end
```

Didn't test this out, so there might be some error here.

Comment: Cleaning it up like that is easier, so thanks for the suggestion, but I'm still having the same problem when I do: `include_examples "get_user_in", signin_path` which is what I'd really like to be able to do.

Comment: would `before { visit "#{path}_path" }` do that for you?

Comment: That wouldn't work. `signin_path` should evaluate to something like `"/signin"`. The real problem is that the method `signin_path` is undefined, apparently only outside of `it` blocks.